# Default layout for ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I am currently using an array adapter. All the examples that I came across online use a separate layout for the array adapter. I wanted to know if it had a default layout. My code is something like this

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapt = new  ArrayAdapter<String>(this,,item);
```

What should  the second parameter so that I dont specify a resource layout and it uses its default ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the defalut one `TextView` row item:

```
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
```

like so:

```
   ArrayAdapter<String> adapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items)
```